# Revert git commits without doing new commit

Tags: git

Is it possible to revert git commits without doing a new commit to revert those commits?

This will create a new commit at the end:

```
$ git revert --no-commit D
$ git revert --no-commit C
$ git revert --no-commit B
$ git commit -m "the commit message"
```

Comment: No it isn't possible.

Comment: `git rebase -i HEAD~1`

Comment: Are you in a situation where it is acceptable to re-write the history?

Comment: The only things that are a permanent part of a repository are the commits. If you don't care about permanance, you can use `git revert -n` (aka `--no-commit`) to back out stuff in your work-tree, and then just leave your work-tree different from your commits. You can even use a `--mixed` reset to make your index match your `HEAD` commit. But the version with the backed-out changes won't be saved permanently until you commit it.

Answer (score 1):

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

**Warning**: The above command will permanently remove the modifications to your files of your last commit. Can be dangerous

Comment: So I first have to perform the reverts, commit the reverts and then this?

Comment: No, you just need to specify commit you want go back to instead of `HEAD~1`. Right now this command will bring you back one commit back

Comment: In case you already push commit you want to delete to the remote, it can be dangerous to do that because you rewrite the history. But if it's not an issue, this is the good solution to revert LAST commit

Comment: What if the commits to be reverted aren't the last ones?

Comment: As I said you need to specify `SHA` of needed commit instead of `HEAD~1`

Comment: @luminousmen Won't that remove commits that need to be kept?

Comment: @juanchopanza yes, that's what my answer says

Comment: If it said that (it doesn't) then it wouldn't be clear how it could be useful to remove something that needs to be kept.